# Shared worlds: are there any good collaborative sites out there?

Tags: fiction, collaboration, shared, world-building

Writing is something that I have wanted to do for some time, and I know that I don't currently have the skill set to do more than putter.  Are there any shared world story sites that exist?  A collaborative site for me to get my feet wet handling a supporting character or two, rather than trying to wrangle the whole plot, would be ideal.

Comment: See http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/108/are-there-any-places-to-have-community-story-development

Comment: So should we consolidate?  This one was first, but didn't get as many answers because of poor word choice in the title (I am guessing).

Comment: I think a link is fine. People browsing this could be directed to the other question through the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know of a few shared world out there, some are more open then others it really depends on what sort of genre you're looking to write in.

Up here in Pacific Northwest is a setting called "New Cascadia" which is one of those community sent back in time thing... though in this case it most of western Washington and Oregon. I know there is quiet a bit of writing in that setting, and it's large enough to have room to do something without any trouble, but for the life of me I can't find any website for them.

I'll have to ask around with some of the people who I know have worked on it, though that won't be until the next convention.

Comment: I'm curious to know if anything became of this?

Answer (score 3):

What a fascinating concept, Larry! I fully realise that you're probably long past the need for a 'shared world story site' but nonetheless I decided to have a look for my own interest.

After a lot of fruitless scrabbling through the far reaches of the internet I finally came across [Story Timed](http://www.storytimed.com/), which seems to match your (then) interests and (now) mine.

The About page says:

> This site is all about writing stories together. There are two types of stories that you can contribute to on this site. We call them "Open Book" and "Closed Book" stories.

Sounds promising, right?

Okay, I'm off to Sign Up. Join me?