# Story-Telling on the Internet

Tags: fiction, community

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet communities where I can read/rate/review short fiction, and post my own?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/internet-communities-where-i-can-read-rate-review-short-fiction-and-post-my-own)

I am a user of Cowbird already, and I love it, but I want to branch out, and go to other story-telling sites, so I can get more feedback.  I just want another community to go to, and I don't really need much else ^^

Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe these two questions have you covered: http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/internet-communities-where-i-can-read-rate-review-short-fiction-and-post-my-own? and http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/108/are-there-any-places-to-have-community-story-development? . I'm closing this as a duplicate; let me know if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Yep, it's pretty much a duplicate ^^