# Good screenwriting-specific collaboration software

Tags: software, screenwriting, tools, collaboration

My brother and I want to work on a screenplay together and are looking for a true real-time collaboration software that is also secure.  [Plotbot](http://www.plotbot.com/) shows edits by all parties in real-time, but you have to trust Plotbot to safeguard your script as it lives on their server.  I have tried [Celtx](https://www.celtx.com/index.html) but it wasn't true real-time.  In fact, we never could figure out what series of steps finally synced the scripts.  It made me nervous that text would be lost.

Has anyone had a good experience working collaboratively on a screenplay and would like to share what tools they used?

Edit: I know tools like Google Docs exist and while it has good collaboration tools, it doesn't have screenwriting-specific tools like formatting, cards, timelines etc. I am not looking for collaborative *writing* tools but rather collaborative *screenwriting* tools.

Comment: Look here https://zapier.com/blog/collaborative-writing-tools-editorially-draft-penflip/ for a review on some tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/7126/software-for-collaborative-writing-for-a-small-team

Comment: Edited to address duplication.

Comment: Did you have a look at join.me? http://chipstreet.com/2012/02/08/the-best-collaborative-screenwriting-software-tool-ever/

Comment: I have used join.me for training and presentation and such but my brother and I probably won't often be working on the script at the same time.  He has a very haphazard schedule.  I might try it for the times when we are together.

Comment: I think that this question is sufficiently different to count as a non-duplicate.

Comment: @zkent - Rather than asking for people's experiences, as one would on a forum, can you go into more detail on what you need to be able to do? I imagine there won't be a tool that exactly suits your needs, but it would help us narrow it down.

Comment: What about WriterDuet and Adobe Story Free? Adobe Story Free can be accessed on the Adobe cloud so people can collaborate per se (not in its exact sense though). WriterDuet offers some good collaboration.

Comment: When you are collaborating, some or the other kind of server based interaction (I think) would come into the picture. You will not be able to completely eliminate that interaction. Like @NeilFein said, you could go into more detail on what you need to be able to do

Answer (score 3):

Since we never put anything out on a public server, aka Cloud, I don't know if Trelby is what you need or not.
On the bright side, it's FREE, so no harm in taking a look to see.
I've never heard of Plotbot, but have used Celtx.

The number one screenwriting software is Final Draft.  It is expensive, crashes often, and not universal among platforms.  For this reason, serious screenwriters are drifting away from the slow behemoth.

Trelby is fast and easy to use.  No known problems with it, other than copy n paste is difficult to master, unless they fixed this since the last time I used it.

Celtx had a slight delay that became more annoying the longer I used it.  But as you pointed out, it's not real time and not truly collaborative.

We use a commercial server version of something that looks like Final Draft at work, and I know several are working on the same project at the same time from all over the country.  But I'm not in that department, nor do I know if the home version has the same features.  The only thing I can say for certain about Final Draft is it crashes way to often.  Nor do they support universal publishers platforms.  For these reasons I would not fork over the high price they want for it.

I wish I could give you a better information about Trelby.  Those I know who use it, rave about it, so it must be good.

VTY
Dutch